# System.Web.HttpException: 'Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I realise that this question has been asked in various forms a number of times, but I have not found a solution that solves my issue.

I am writing a web site to record details of dead people. My web page has a title drop down box and a sex drop down box.

In the database, these are linked and I need to set the sex based on the title.

I have a list box that contains the title id / sex id link and a function to look up the sex from the title using this list box.

```
<asp:Label CssClass="LegacyLabel">Title</asp:Label>
<asp:ListBox ID="TitleSex" runat="server" CssClass="hidethis" SelectionMode="Single"></asp:ListBox>
<asp:DropDownList ID="LegatorTitle" runat="server" CssClass="LegacyDDL" TabIndex="2" onchange="setSex()"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:Label CssClass="LegacyLabel">Sex</asp:Label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="LegatorSex" runat="server" CssClass="LegacyDDL" TabIndex="5"></asp:DropDownList>

<script>
function setSex() {
    var t = document.getelementbyid("<%=LegatorTitle.ClientID %>");
    var ts = document.getElementById("<%=TitleSex.ClientID %>");
    var s = document.getElementById("<%=LegatorSex.ClientID %>");
    //get title selectd value
    var tValue = t.options[t.selectedIndex].value;
    var opts = ts.options;
    //set the title sex selected value
    ts.selectedItem.selected = false;
    for (var z0 = 0; z0 < opts.length; z0++) {
        if (opts[z0].value == tValue) {
            ts.selectedIndex = z0;
            break;
        }
    }
    //get the title sex selected text
    var tsText = ts.options[ts.selectedIndex].text;
    opts = s.options;
    //set the sex selected value
    s.selectedItem.selected = false;
    for (z0 = 0; z0 < opts.length; z0++) {
        if (opts[z0].value == tsText) {
            s.selectedIndex = z0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The drop down lists and list box are set from a web service using datatables

```
dataTable = fcws.GetTitles(UNAME, PWORD)
LegatorTitle.Items.Clear()
LegatorTitle.DataSource = dataTable
LegatorTitle.DataTextField = "TitleName"
LegatorTitle.DataValueField = "TitleId"
LegatorTitle.DataBind()

TitleSex.Items.Clear()
TitleSex.DataSource = dataTable
TitleSex.DataTextField = "SexId"
TitleSex.DataValueField = "TitleId"
TitleSex.DataBind()
dataTable = fcws.GetTitles(UNAME, PWORD)
LegatorTitle.Items.Clear()
LegatorTitle.DataSource = dataTable
LegatorTitle.DataTextField = "TitleName"
LegatorTitle.DataValueField = "TitleId"
LegatorTitle.DataBind()

'sex
dataTable = fcws.GetSexes(UNAME, PWORD)
LegatorSex.Items.Clear()
LegatorSex.DataSource = dataTable
LegatorSex.DataTextField = "SexName"
LegatorSex.DataValueField = "SexId"
LegatorSex.DataBind()
```

I also have case opened and case closed dates and a status (drop down list with Open and Close options)

When I try to load an open case, everything works perfectly

When I try to load a closed case, I get the following error

```
    Server Error in '/' Application

    Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList

    Source error

    Line 245:            var t = document.getelementbyid("<%=LegatorTitle.ClientID %>");
    Line 246:            var ts = document.getElementById("<%=TitleSex.ClientID %>");
--> Line 247:            var s = document.getElementById("<%=LegatorSex.ClientID %>"); <---
    Line 248:            //get title selected value
    Line 249:            var tValue = t.options[t.selectedIndex].value;
```

(--> ... <-- is highlighted line)

[I cannot post images yet so here is a link to the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGDtW.png)

What I don't understand is: -

1. why the error occurs in the first place
2. why the error is only occurring for closed cases
3. why, when I change the line 
   'var s = document.getElementById("<%=LegatorSex.ClientID %>");' to 'var s = document.getElementById("LegatorSex");', the error moves to the line var ts = document.getElementById("<%=TitleSex.ClientID %>"); 
   (if I change all the lines in the above code, the error moves to the previous line with <%=xxx.ClientID %>)

I have checked responses that were helpful (that is why I clear the lists before binding to them and why I set the selectedItem.selected to false before re-setting it) to the downright unhelpful (The error is pretty specific: You can't have multiple selections in a drop down list. Find another control which fits your needs better!) but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Starter for 10 - Line 245: `document.getelementbyid` should be `document.getElementById`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer
(and I feel a bit stupid that I didn't spot this before...)

As part of the job, I had to default the case status to open for new cases. The code I added to set the case status to open was being run for all cases, not just new ones.

Open cases worked fine because the selection was already set to "open"

Many thanks for your input and very sorry for wasting your time over my stupidity

I still have no idea why the error reports the failing line as one with

'getelementbyid("<%=xxx.ClientID %>");'